# Xcode not finding my custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift

I am working in swift and I have two files: arcade.swift and card.swift. card.swift is my class that has some properties

```
import Foundation
import spriteKit

class card{
    var width = 0
    var color = ""
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var match = card()
    var id = 0
}
```

and my other class arcade is simply trying to make a new instance of card and set the width. I feel like I am missing something extremely easy.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import spriteKit

class arcade: UIViewController {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var myCard = card()
myCard.width = 50  //gives me an error - "expected declaration"
}
```

Comment: wow duh, thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myCard.width = 50` has to be within a function.

Unrelated,  your `card` class (btw, by convention, classes usually start with uppercase letters) has a property that instantiated another `card` object. That will likely result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You don't need the import statement at all. As long as your class is in the same project, you can just use it and xcode will recognise it right away. Just remember the functions you are trying to acces in your code can not be private, but should at least be "internal" You might want to read more here in [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)
Probably a "Struct" is more appropriate for what you re trying to do. However, just remember that structs are always used as "pass-by value" (the Struct is copied), whereas objects from classes are alway "pass-by reference" (pointer to memory)